# Writing a JSON (or TXT) file in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

I have been trying to make sense of this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx which uses the SaveFileDialog, but it is hard for me to understand.  I have the following code:

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\cle1394\\Desktop\\Apple Foreign Tax Payment Sample Layout Proposed - Sample Data.xlsx");

ConsoleApplication2.Program.ExcelData data = ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData(existingFile);

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
```

How can I output the contents of `json` to a `.json` or `.txt` file?

I would like to let the user either see a link/ button to click to download/ save the file to a location on their computer, or, simply display the save file dialog box so that they can save the file to a location on their computer.

EDIT (to let OP comment on what parts are not clear):

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
{
   File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName,json);   
}
```

Comment: `json` variable is a `string` by the way.

Comment: With that much points, you would know you can edit the question and add more info. ;)

Comment: @Mario What info do you need?  I feel all you should need to know is that `json` is a `string`.  Basically, I need to know how to output a string to a file in C#/ WPF.

Comment: Just follow the sample from your link and use `File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, json)` to save the data.

Comment: I meant that you can add more info to the question instead of in a comment.

Comment: Really!! How would you write strings to a text file? :) See chapter: File Handling

Comment: @Nayan A little more specific than that:  How can I write a string to a text file using the SaveFileDialog class.

Comment: @user1477388 You need to learn 2 things, separately - writing text to file, and second, how to use SaveFileDialog component. You have got answers already for them frm user `ie` in comments here.

Comment: @Nayan Yes, but I am not able to decipher which is which.  It would be helpful to have a full example of how to write to a file using the SaveFileDialog using my code above.  The answers/comments here just show a one-liner that doesn't really seem to solve the problem I am having.

Comment: File text writing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx

Comment: Dialog http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx

Comment: And for kids :) http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog

Comment: I've edit your post so you can comment on what exactly is not clear to you (combined sample from your link with WriteAllText link). If it is exactly what you are looking for - feel free to convert into "That is what I  wanted" and consider to accept Icurus' anser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this, then:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\some\path\json.txt",json);
```

And note that it will save the file using UTF8-encoding without a Byte Order Mark. If you need the BOM, you need to use the `File.WriteAllText(path, content, Enconding);`

[See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376.aspx)

**Update**  - adding sample with SaveFileDialog:

```
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFileDialog.FileName))
 {
     //saveFileDialog.FileName should contain the full path
     //according to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx
     File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName,json);

 }
```

Comment: How do I apply this with the SaveFileDialog?  I understand it has a filestream like `System.IO.FileStream fs`

Comment: OP asked for answer in conjunction with `saveFileDialog`, which is missing in answer.

Comment: This code gives me an error on `DialogResult.OK` that reads "'System.Nullable<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'Ok' and no extension method 'Ok' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @user1477388 - I have edited your question and example has been provided.